# Poisson, Negative Binomial, and zero-inflated Poisson and Negative Binomial within a multilevel modeling context

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, count-data, zero-inflation

I’m analyzing count data (e.g., number of students with suspensions), and the outcomes also have many 0s.  The data are also nested (schools within districts).  I’m familiar with using Poisson and Zero-Inflated Poisson regression, and I’m gaining familiarity with Negative Binomial and Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial.  Based on what I know, I’m fairly confident I can rule out Poisson due to over dispersion, and  I’m thinking ZIP gets ruled out for the same reason (but I’m not as confident on that point).

I'm struggling to apply some of this in a multilevel modeling framework, along with how exactly to make the decision between types.  I believe I understand the idea behind zero-inflation where there is a separate process, if you will, accounting for some of the excess 0s, but I haven’t been able to come up with a way that fits in my project theoretically, so I'm inclined to think Negative Binomial is the best choice at the moment.  I've been referring to *Multilevel Modeling Using R* (Finch, Bolin, & Kelley, 2014 and 2019), but they do not discuss zero-inflation.

I would really appreciate any specific papers, particularly focused on education or psychology examples, or additional resources for using these regression techniques in R.

Comment: How interested in you are modeling the 0/1 dichotomy? If a lot, then the advantage of zero-inflated models is that you can have an explicit model for whether an observation is 0/1. If not interested, then the negative binomial model takes care of the overdispersion problem (more as a nuisance). Check out https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/r/overdispersion. In R, you can use GLMMadaptive for multilevel models for count data (Poisson or Neg Binomial): https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/